# NullPointerException when using ButterKnife in multimodule project with fragment

Tags: android, module, nullpointerexception, fragment, butterknife

I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` when app is resumed after being in backgroung for a few minutes.

My root buildscript:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.4.0'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
}
```

And my library module gradle has:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In my Fragment which is being resumed is properly bind the views,
but somehow the binding is lost when resuming the app.

```
@BindView(R2.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView recyclerView;
@BindView(R2.id.viewPager) ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(getFragmentLayoutId(), container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();

    if (unbinder != null)
    {
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

I'm not using proguard, and the exception is also thrown on some occasions during page is changed in viewPager.
Both viewPager and recyclerView is being null on time to time.

The exception is thrown here:

```
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener getOnPageChangeListener()
{
    return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {}
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            if (position != list.size())
            {
                if (isSelectedActive())
                {
                    animateSelectedToActive();
                }
                else
                {
                    animateSelectedToInactive();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

private void animateSelectedToActive()
{
    // -- Exception thrown here ! --
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.animate().alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(370)
            .start();
}
```

Have I missed something, I followed how to implement it line by line?

Comment: Where in your code is this exception thrown? Please indicate the line.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information, the exception has also been thrown in other places but this one is more frequent. :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to include the default bindview aka R instead of using the library one?

Answer (score -1):

Its may be because `Fragment` is depends on `Activity context` and dont have his own `context`. So you must do `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` in `Activity`, which starts your `Fragment`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: According to http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ , ButterKnife.bind(this, view); has to be used :/